# $\operatorname{Cov}(x,Y)$ in linear regression model

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$Let $Y_i=a+bx_i+\varepsilon$ the simple regression model. The expression of the pearson coefficien is given by

$$\rho_{xY}=\frac{\Cov(x,Y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_Y}.$$

My question is about the interpretion of $\Cov(x,Y)$ and $\sigma_x$, since $x$ is not random.

I think that
$$\Cov(x,Y)=\Cov(x,a+bx+\varepsilon)=\Cov(x,a)+\Cov(x,bx)+\Cov(x,\varepsilon)=b\Cov(x,x)$$
$$\Cov(x,Y)=b\cdot\operatorname{Var}(x).$$

Is this correct? What is the interpretation of this result?

Comment: If you're wondering about the interpretation of the expression $\rho_{xY} = \dfrac{\operatorname{Cov}(x,Y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_Y}, \vphantom{\frac.{\displaystyle\sum}}$ that seems to suggest that someone other than yourself used that expression. In what context did it come up? Sometimes $X$ and $Y$ are both random but $X$ is treated as non-random because what is of interest is only the _conditional_ distribution of $Y$ _given_ $X.$ In other contexts, an experimenter can judiciously choose the $x$ values and then nature provides the $Y$ values. $\qquad$

Comment: The context is that $Y|x\sim N(a+bx,\sigma^2)$ and I'm trying to prove that $\rho_{xY}^2=R^2$ (coefficient of determination).

Comment: If $X$ is random and $\operatorname E(Y\mid X) = a+bX$ and $\operatorname{var}(Y\mid X) = \sigma^2,$ then the value of $R^2$ arising from an i.i.d. sample $(X_i,Y_i),\,\,i=1,\ldots,n$ is in general _not_ equal to the square of the correlation between $X$ and $Y,$ although it approaches that as $n\to\infty. \qquad $

Comment: Is there any reference where I can check the proof of this asymptotic result?

Comment: On the other hand, if you have fixed, not random, values of $x_i,$ then you can examine the distribution of $R^2,$ (which is a random variable if $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are random), but I don't know what $\text{“}\rho^2\text{''}$ would mean in that case. $\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$but now that you mention it, I think there may be only one sensible way to define $\rho^2$ in that last case, but then the same remark about $R^2\to\rho^2$ as $n\to\infty$ would apply. $\qquad$

Comment: My first thought is Serfling's book _Limit Theorems of Mathematical Statistics_. $\qquad$

Comment: In the case of $X$ being random, it is correct that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=b\cdot\operatorname{Var}(X). \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$and BTW, there is no need to assume anything is normally distributed to get that equality. Just $\operatorname E(Y\mid X) = a+bX$ and $\operatorname{var}(Y\mid X) = \sigma^2<+\infty$ and $\operatorname{var}(X)<+\infty$ is enough. And here the import of the statement $\operatorname{var}(Y\mid X) = \sigma^2<+\infty$ is not just that the conditional variance is finite but also that that it does not depend on $X. \qquad$

Comment: I like this way of expressing that equality: $$ \frac{\operatorname E(Y\mid X) - \operatorname E(Y)}{\operatorname{sd}(Y)} = \rho\cdot\frac{X - \operatorname E(X)}{\operatorname{sd}(X)}. $$ I.e. multiply the $z$-score for $X$ by $\rho$ to get the expected (conditional) $z$-score for $Y. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

$Cov(X,Y)$ is only defined for two random variables $X$ and $Y$. The notation $x$, as in $Cov(x,Y)$,  implies that the random variable is degenerated, that is, $Prob(X=x)=1$. In such a case, $Cov(x,Y)=0$. On the other hand, it is not unheard of that people use (misuse) the notation of $Cov(x,y)$ to stand for a computational formula. I suspect that this may be the case here.